# How to change the default terminal directory?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>, the terminal is open in $HOME dir.

I want to open it in `/tmp` instead.

Thus:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>
- Terminal is open at `/tmp`

Is it possible?

How can I configure it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding `cd /tmp` to your `.bashrc`, bash will go to `/tmp` directly after you open a Terminal.

Comment: Adding it to `.bashrc` may confuse some scripts. At a minimum, `.bash_login` would be better.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- `.bash_login` shouldn't be used for this. The shell in a graphical terminal application (Ctrl+Alt+T) in Ubuntu--and just about any GNU/Linux system--isn't a login shell so none of `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, or `.bash_login` is sourced. Also, creating `.bash_login` (or `.bash_profile`) causes bash to source it *instead* of, rather than in addition to, `.profile`, for login shells (as one gets when logging in on a virtual console or via SSH). On Ubuntu, the default contents of `.profile` are substantial. `cd /tmp` in `.bashrc` is fairly safe if placed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This will open a terminal at the /tmp directory.

```
$ mate-terminal --working-directory=/tmp/
```

Comment: Should probably add some explanation.

Comment: Looks like OP has « gnome-terminal » as a tag, this command is for mate !